# Error in MYSQL trigger after update

Tags: mysql

Hi i have a problem with mysql trigger this is my code and the error that appears is this:
Error1064 :You have errors in your MYSQL sintax near insert...

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_HISTORIALES AFTER UPDATE ON BOARD
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    IF (OLD.IMEI != NEW.IMEI)
    INSERT INTO HISTORIAL_CAMBIO_IMEI (HISTORIAL_CAMBIO_ID,FECHA,BOARD_ID,IMEI_ANTERIOR,IMEI_NUEVO)
    VALUES
    (NULL,SYSDATE(),SELECT BOARD_ID FROM BOARD WHERE IMEI=OLD.IMEI,SYSDATE(),OLD.IMEI,NEW.IMEI);
    END IF
    END
```

Comment: It looks like there are five fields and six values in your `insert` statement. Can you retrieve the complete error message?

Comment: i believe the 2nd `SYSDATE()` does not correspond with your column list - either delete it or add a column name after `BOARD_ID`